# How to get a true modular app in AngularJS and their include structure?

Tags: angularjs, get, include, modularity, file-structure

I've been messing around with Angular and i wanted to split all the files up according to their role in my app.

I want a folder for each "page" like /home or /products and take care of everything within their respective folder(It sounded like a great idea).

However, now i'm not sure how to approach loading these files in or even where to do it.

This is my current file structure: 
[image]

Due to certain limitations im not able to use other helpful tools, this needs to happen in the code directly.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: You'll most likely want some sort of task runner like Grunt to merge all your source files into a single file that you require in your index.html

Comment: use gulp or grunt task managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st part of your question:

There's no ***default*** way to organise your angular app.

However, there are some guidelines. I keep thanking myself for reading the [***Angular 1 app-structuring-guidelines*** by **John Pappa**](https://johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/) which enlightened me on the same question you are asking.

At the moment, I have organised all my apps in a folder-by-functionality apprach rather than a folder-by-type one (i.e. all controllers in a controllers folder, all services in a services folder,etc).

2nd part of your question: 
Just use Gulp or Grunt and then import the single file in your index

---

Comment: [Todd Motto's Angular 1.6 with ES2015](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide) is another good resource for constructing a component based Angular web application.

Comment: Completely agree with you, did not intend to support one guy only. Todd Motto's guides are great as well

Comment: Don't worry, I have used John Papa's styleguide a dozen of times as well, both present different approaches though

Answer (score 1):

The Web is getting more and more component oriented, now all the most famous frontend frameworks adopt a reusable component policy (React and Angular 2 relies heavily on it)

If you want your angular app to be as modular as possible, you have to put everything regarding a component in a separate folder (html templates,css styles and js logic),and split the shared logic between  services and assets

In Your case an example of project structure could be:

app/

- assets/
  //put here images,fonts and shared styles
- services/

  - apiService.js
  - utilsService.js
  - etc etc ...
- components

  - home/

    - home.js
    - home.css
    - home.html
  - products/

    - products.js
    - products.css
    - products.html
  - etc etc/...
  - index.js

index.html